Need help on how to approach a SQL query taking a lot of time
My problem is that I needed to create a query which is helping me determine some info needed related to time zones.
This is my query:
WITH time_data AS (
    SELECT
        CL.id_time,
        CAST(UTC_DST_Start AS DATETIME) AS UTC_DST_Start,
        CAST(UTC_DST_End AS DATETIME) AS UTC_DST_End,
        CAST(off_minutes AS INT64) AS off_minutes,
        CAST(day_off_minutes AS INT64) AS day_off_minutes
    FROM time_year_data AS CL
    JOIN time_off_data AS TZO
    ON TZO.id_time = CL.id_time
    WHERE
    StandardDescription = 'Eastern Standard Time'
        -- StandardDescription IN ('Eastern Standard Time', 'Central Standard Time', 'Mountain Standard Time', 'Pacific Standard Time')
        AND Year >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -2 YEAR)
),
time_ents AS (
    SELECT
        Id,
        TimeEntry_Id,
        ClientID,
        StartTime,
        EndTime
    FROM vw_time_ents
),
time_adj AS (
    SELECT
        TE.*,
        TZ.id_time,
        DATETIME_ADD(CAST(StartTime AS DATETIME), INTERVAL
            CASE WHEN CAST(StartTime AS DATETIME) BETWEEN TZ.UTC_DST_Start AND TZ.UTC_DST_End
                THEN TZ.day_off_minutes ELSE TZ.off_minutes
            END MINUTE) AS Start_TZ,
        DATETIME_ADD(CAST(EndTime AS DATETIME), INTERVAL
            CASE WHEN CAST(EndTime AS DATETIME) BETWEEN TZ.UTC_DST_Start AND TZ.UTC_DST_End
                THEN TZ.day_off_minutes ELSE TZ.off_minutes
            END MINUTE) AS End_TZ
    FROM time_ents TE
    JOIN time_data TZ ON DATE_TRUNC(CAST(TZ.UTC_DST_Start AS DATE), YEAR) = DATE_TRUNC(CAST(TE.StartTime AS DATE), YEAR)
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    Id,
    TimeEntry_Id,
    ClientID,
    StartTime,
    EndTime,
    Start_TZ,
    End_TZ,
    IFNULL(CASE
        WHEN CAST(Start_TZ AS DATE) <> CAST(End_TZ AS DATE) THEN DATETIME_DIFF(CAST(End_TZ AS DATETIME), DATETIME_ADD(CAST(CAST(End_TZ AS DATE) AS DATETIME), INTERVAL 1 SECOND), SECOND) + 1
        ELSE 0
    END, 0) AS DurationOne,
    CASE
        WHEN CAST(StartTime AS DATE) = CAST(EndTime AS DATE) THEN DATETIME_DIFF(CAST(EndTime AS DATETIME), CAST(StartTime AS DATETIME), SECOND)
        ELSE DATETIME_DIFF(DATETIME_ADD(CAST(CAST(StartTime AS DATE) AS DATETIME), INTERVAL 86399 SECOND), CAST(StartTime AS DATETIME), SECOND) + 1
    END AS DurationTwo
FROM time_adj

Now this query is good, it does what I want and doesn't clog up resources, so my issue is the following.
As you can see in this line
StandardDescription = 'Eastern Standard Time'

I'm specifying a timezone, my final table will show a start time and en time for this particular timezone, the problem that I have is that I need to produce a table with all start and end for these time zones 'Eastern Standard Time', 'Central Standard Time', 'Mountain Standard Time', 'Pacific Standard Time'.
My first approach was an aberration that while it work it was too heavy on resources, I was able to come up with this one but it only does one time zone at a time.
So how can I get the final table without overloading the whole thing?
I was thinking creating 4 views based on this code and then just a join, but I'm not sure if that approach is the same as copying the code 4 times in the same query and do the joins in there.
Any suggestions will be appreciated.

"I was thinking creating 4 views based on this code and then just a join, but I'm not sure if that approach is the same as copying the code 4 times in the same query and do the joins in there" yes this would be essentially the same. I'm not a user of biqquery but in principle you can/should be able to create parameterized queries where you pass in a timezone as a parameter (so one query but still has to run four time).

It should also be possible run the query for four times zones at once and return all the results together .... although it seems you tried that and found the results were slow. If you want to try to improve on that approach you might want to post that attempt.
